# Combine two DataFrame tables, aggregate Data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
array = pd.DataFrame(np.object, index=[], columns=[])
array = array.append({'Project': b.name, 'Summary': card.name, \
                      'Key': card.id, 'Assignee': m, 'Points': s}, \
                      ignore_index=True)
array1 = pd.read_excel('ProjectCostUCP.xlsx', 'Лист1')
result = array[['Project', 'Assignee', 'Points']].groupby(['Project', 
                                             'Assignee']).sum(axis=1)
print(result.columns.tolist()) #HERE IS ONLY 'Points' BUT MUST BE 'Project' 
                                              AND 'Asignee' ALSO !!!
result = result.merge(array1, on=['Project'])
result['Value'] = result.Points * result.Price
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('third.xlsx')
array.to_excel(writer, "June")
result.to_excel(writer, "June_agregation")
writer.save()
```

However, I get KeyError from this code, because in result array there is no 'Project' column and the `merge()` function doesn't work. 
After the `grouby()` function call there is only one column - 'Points'.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply a **[mcve]**. You can mock up a simple dataframe with 3 rows. This will be more useful than a code dump we can't replicate.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to answer the question - is to use reset_index() function. After using grouby() function we need to reset MultiIndex to index. In code it wiil be:

```
result.reset_index().merge(array1, on=['Project'])
```